# Generated Key looks wrong when ManyToOne and OneToMany

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two entities with a relationship, UserEntity:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId extends EntityId implements Serializable {

   @Column( length = CCEntity.ID_MAX_SIZE, name = ccIdCN )
   private String ccId;

   @Column( length = NAME_MAX_SIZE, name = userIdCN )
   private String userId;

   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = TableNames.CC_Users)
public class UserEntity {

   @EmbeddedId
   private UserId id;

...

   @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProfileEntity.class, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
   private List<ProfileEntity> profiles;
```

And the ProfileEntity:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProfileId extends EntityId implements Serializable {

   @Column( length = CCEntity.ID_MAX_SIZE, name = ccIdCN )
   private String ccId;

   @Column( length = NAME_MAX_SIZE, name = profileIdCN )
   private String profileId;

   ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = TableNames.CC_Profile)
public class ProfileEntity {

   @EmbeddedId
   protected ProfileId id;

...

   @ManyToOne 
   @JoinColumns(value = { 
      @JoinColumn( nullable = true, name = Columns.referenceIdCN, referencedColumnName = UserId.userIdCN ),
      @JoinColumn( nullable = true, name = Columns.ccIdOfReferenceCN, referencedColumnName = UserId.ccIdCN ),
   })
   private UserEntity user;
```

When JPA creates the tables it generates the following:
Table CC_USER with primary key: **cc_id, user_id**. That is correct.
Table CC_PROFILE with primary key: **cc_id, user_id, profile_id**. Here I don't understand why JPA adds the **user_id** column as primary key. The table also has the columns: **reference_id** and **cc_id_of_reference_id** set as nullable.

I want property user of the ProfileEntity is optional, or nullable. If I try to add an entity with the user as null, I get :

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null
>   value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

thanks for any help

Comment: Can you post the code of the `EntityId`?

Comment: There is no indication in your code where a user_id field in CC_PROFILE might be coming from, as JPA would be using Columns.referenceIdCN instead, so something else must be going on.  Turn on EclipseLink logging to FINEST and check out the messages when it is processing the persistence unit - this should show field by field what it is picking up and might give a clue where the cc_profile.user_id field is coming from.  Check how you are building and deploying, as it could be the persistence unit is picking up an old version that still has user_id set to be the foreign key.

Comment: @Chris, thanks. I turn on the log and I see the query to create the table: CREATE TABLE cc_user_profile (... cc_id VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL, user_id VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL, ... profile_id VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL, reference_id VARCHAR(127), cc_id_of_reference_id VARCHAR(127), PRIMARY KEY (cc_id, user_id, profile_id)). But no clue why is creating that primary key. How could I "refresh" persistence unit in case is picking up an old version?

Comment: @Nikos, the code of both ids is there. Below "Embeddable"

Comment: @Chris, I am running a test case from Eclipse. I don't have troubles with old files. When I change persistence.xml I see changes after running the test. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with eclipselink version 2.6.4, and also with 2.7.1 (current version). But still see the issue.

Comment: I decided to set the ManyToOne and the OneToMany to Transient, to remove the fields from the metadata. The generated table still has the wrong key, with the user_id field. So, the issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. I have another Entity with same TableName as ProfileEntity, but a different id. That id contains the user_id column that wasn't expected.